# How to call Add New Item window inside an Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am developing an visual studio extension. As a part of it I need to call "Add New Item" window of Visual Studio.

After prompting this I need the User input also back with file name.

How to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code. This does the job

```
 var type = typeof(VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID);

        var commandId = new CommandID(type.GUID, (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.AddClass);

        var oleMenuCommandService = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;

        oleMenuCommandService.GlobalInvoke(commandId);
```

Reference :- Link [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014018.aspx)